# RecyclerView + Room, некие баги

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-room

Здрасте. При регистрации новой data не показывается в recyclerView

SomeDataRecyclerAdapter:

```java
public class SomeDataRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnDeleteListener onDeleteListener;
    private Context context;

    public SomeDataRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataModels = dataModels;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_some_data, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final NewsViewHolder viewHolder = (NewsViewHolder) holder;
        viewHolder.title.setText(dataModels.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.description.setText(dataModels.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModels.size();
    }

    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.title)
        public TextView title;
        @BindView(R.id.description)
        public TextView description;
        @BindView(R.id.delete)
        public TextView delete;

        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            delete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                onDeleteListener.onDelete(dataModels.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                dataModels.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            });
        }
    }

    public void setOnDeleteListener(OnDeleteListener onDeleteListener) {
        this.onDeleteListener = onDeleteListener;
    }

    public interface OnDeleteListener {
        void onDelete(DataModel dataModel);
    }
}
```

DataModel:

```java
@Entity
public class DataModel {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    @ColumnInfo
    private Integer title;
    @ColumnInfo
    private String description;


    @NonNull
    public Integer getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(@NonNull Integer title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Dao:

```java
@Dao
public interface DataDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(DataModel dataModel);

    @Delete
    void delete(DataModel dataModel);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM DataModel")
    List<DataModel> getAllData();
}
```

DatabaseHelper:

```java
@Database(entities = { DataModel.class }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DatabaseHelper extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract DataDao getDataDao();

    @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

App:

```java
public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;
    private static DatabaseHelper db;

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.class, "data-database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    public static DatabaseHelper getDatabaseInstance() {
        return db;
    }
}
```

Git: https://github.com/enotit/ced.git

Comment: А с чего они должны обновляться? Вы их нигде не обновляете (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()) там где добавляете данные или используйте LiveData

Comment: @Valeriy , Не особо вас понимаю, можем ли мы пройти куда нибудь? Я только недавно начал изучать Андроид

Comment: https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-recyclerview/

Comment: если вы хотите, чтобы при изменении в базе данных, данные в списке  обновлялись автоматически, [используйте support.v7.ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) (еще [пример использования](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb))  из библиотеки поддержки начиная с версии 27.1.0 (не путать с  ListAdapter из API для ListView). Так же не стоит забывать, что сейчас идет миграция от библиотек поддержки support в androidX и учесть это в будущем